# When does "Not all updates can be installed" warning appear

Tags: package-management, software-updater

In what circumstances (package problems, download problems, etc) does the following image appear:

[image]

What is the difference between clicking on the **Continue** button or the **Partial Upgrade** button and what are the steps to solve this issue when it appears.

Comment: I can't tell you why this happens but I find that if I continue with the partial upgrade I eventually reach a level of fully upgraded and no longer get this message. I assumed I had to upgrade A before I could upgrade B but I too would like know what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The Information provided on [**Community Help**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/partialupgrade) may helpful for dealing with partial upgrade:

[image]

> During the past few Ubuntu development cycles, we've been flooded with
>   threads asking for assistance related to issues caused by careless
>   usage of the "Partial Upgrade" feature of Update Manager, which hinted
>   to a poor understanding of package management and the way updates
>   happen in the development branch.
>
> In an effort to help with this situation, this document aims to
>   clarify what a Partial Upgrade is, and why, in most cases, you'll want
>   to avoid it.